# Justify inequality involving real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a, b, d\in\mathbb{R}^*_+, p\in\mathbb{R}, N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N\ge 2$ and $p>1, s\in (0, 1), ps<N$.

Suppose that $a\le d^{Np/(N-ps)}$ and $a+b=d$. I am trying to justify the inequality
$$S(a+b)^{(N-ps)/N}\le a,$$
where $S\le\frac{a}{d^{(N-ps)/N}}.$

Could someone please help me with that?
I tried so far by using triangle inequality, multiplying by something, but I haven’t been successful.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If there are no constraints on $b$, this inequality isn't true (one can blow up LHS by increasing $b$).

Comment: It looks like you can simplify notation. Let $\sigma = \frac{N-ps}N>0$. The assumptions are that
$$ a\le d^{\sigma p}, \quad S \le ad^{-\sigma}$$
and you are trying to show $(a+b)^\sigma S \le a.$

Comment: @Martund you are right, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
S(a+b)^{(N-ps)/N}&\le\frac{a}{d^{(N-ps)/N}}\times(a+b)^{(N-ps)/N}&&\left(\because S\le\frac{a}{d^{(N-ps)/N}}\text{ given}\right)\\
&=a&&\left(\because a+b=d\right)
\end{align}